# Why when I ask for input of char first code work fine . But when I ask for input of integer value it does not ask for char input

Tags: c, scanf

As you can see this code work fine when I ask for char input first It work without any problem.As you can see this code work fine when I ask for char input first It work without any problem.As you can see this code work fine when I ask for char input first It work without any problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char mathoperation;
    int num1,num2;
    printf("Give the math operation you want to use : ");
    scanf("%c",&mathoperation);
    printf("Give the first number of you opperation : ");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("Give the second number of you opperation : ");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    
    switch (mathoperation)
    {
    case '+':
        printf("%d\n",num1+num2);
        break;
    case '-': 
        printf("%d\n",num1-num2);
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("%d\n",num1*num2);
        break;
    case '/':
        if(num2==0)
            printf("No you cant do that");
        else
            printf("%d\n",num1/num2);     
        break;
    case '%':
        printf("%d\n",num1%num2);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Error!");
        break;
    }
        return 0;
}
```

But when I ask for input for the integer value first it does not ask input for char. It directly go to defaut and print error.But when I ask for input for the integer value first it does not ask input for char. It directly go to defaut and print error.But when I ask for input for the integer value first it does not ask input for char. It directly go to defaut and print error.But when I ask for input for the integer value first it does not ask input for char. It directly go to defaut and print error.But when I ask for input for the integer value first it does not ask input for char. It directly go to defaut and print error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char mathoperation;
    int num1,num2;
    printf("Give the math operation you want to use : ");
    scanf("%c",&mathoperation);
    printf("Give the first number of you opperation : ");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("Give the second number of you opperation : ");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    
    switch (mathoperation)
    {
    case '+':
        printf("%d\n",num1+num2);
        break;
    case '-': 
        printf("%d\n",num1-num2);
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("%d\n",num1*num2);
        break;
    case '/':
        if(num2==0)
            printf("No you cant do that");
        else
            printf("%d\n",num1/num2);     
        break;
    case '%':
        printf("%d\n",num1%num2);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Error!");
        break;
    }
        return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVV51.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoR6F.jpg)

Comment: `%d` strips leading whitespace, but `%c` does not.  `\n` is a whitespace character.

Comment: `scanf("%c",&mathoperation);` ==> `scanf(" %c",&mathoperation);` see the added space.

Comment: The `"%c"` does not do "ignore leading whitespace" thing. Try `" %c"`. **Better yet: forget `scanf()` exists and use `fgets()` for user input.**

Comment: What is whitespace means

Comment: One space is a space, two spaces are whitespace. One space and one newline, or tab, etc, or any combination of one of them, or more, all together are whitespace. Placing a space before `%c` instructs `scanf` to remove ***all*** leading whitespace, not just one space.

Comment: Thanks for you help sir.